# Implement 'logout' functionality in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

To get a basic security feature working, I added the following starter package to my pom.xml

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And added following two properties to application.properties:

security.user.name=guest
security.user.password=tiger

Now when I hit my homepage, I get the login box and login works as expected.

Now I want to implement the ‘logout’ feature.  When the user clicks on a link, he/she gets logged out.  I noticed that the login doesn’t add any cookie in my browser.  I am assuming Spring Security creates an HttpSession object for the user.  Is that true?  Do I need to ‘invalidate’ this session and redirect the user to some other page?  What’s the best way to implement the ‘logout’ feature in a Spring Boot based application?

Comment: I would suggest this tutorial: [http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)

Comment: I had already looked at this.  Problem is this is geared toward Spring MVC which is not what I am using.  We've a Spring Boot based application & our UI is served from /resources/public/index.html

Comment: Can I ask how you came upon the starter-security dependency? I've been trying to figure out for DAYS how to run spring security with spring boot and I can't believe it was this easy.

Comment: @Dany - spring-boot-starter-security is mentioned here in the documentation: http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: And how did you know to add those two properties in the application.properties file? Every tutorial I've come across has been similar to this one - where the configuration and username+password is set up in a java class

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Late is better than never. Spring Boot defaults lots of security components for you, including the CSRF protection. One of the things that does is force POST logout, see here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-logout

As this suggests you can override this, using something along the lines of:

```java
http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
.anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
.and()
.formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
.and()
.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
```

The last line is the important one.

Comment: I was looking everywhere for this, thanks, sometimes I feel Spring Boot does too much magic and makes things like this hard to track down

Comment: simple `.logout.permitAll()` will make it. It will redirect to `login/?logout`

Comment: just be careful with GET approach for logout since that can enable attackers to use csrf attack on your website.

Comment: How do I logout with that? window.location = "/login/?logout"; ???

Comment: How will I call it from angular 8 logout method. 
Suppose I have a button log out then how will I call this