# How to log out sucessfully

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, logout

My login page is http://localhost:8080/nradmin/welcome
and my home page (after successful log in) is http://localhost:8080/nradmin/home

I'd like to log out and not anymore be able anymore to access any other page like the home page but only the welcome (login) page. If I type http://localhost:8080/nradmin/home on the browser after logout I continue to have access to the home page without logging in.

I've implemented the following methods overriden from the abstract class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {       http
     .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/home", "/account/**", "/price/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/home", "/account/**", "/price/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
     .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/welcome")  
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
        .and()
     .logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)      
        .clearAuthentication(true)
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/welcome")    
        .logoutUrl("/welcome")          
        .deleteCookies()
        .permitAll()
        .and()
     .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/welcome")           
        .and()
     .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);

}

@Override   
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {        
auth.inMemoryAuthentication()           .withUser("username").password(passwordEncoder().encode("12345")).roles(LoginDataConstants.ROLE_ADMIN)
    }
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it may be due to having the same url in the methods `logoutUrl` and `logoutSuccessUrl`.

I suggest you to change `logoutUrl` to other path, for example just `/logout` and then try to perform the logout hitting that url. It should complete the logout task and the redirect to the `logoutSuccessUrl`, which is `/welcome`

Comment: I've changed the method configure as you said and created a file logout.html as well. But it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Add [CSRF](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-logout)

Reference from spring docs.

> Will perform logout with the URL /logout is requested with any HTTP method

```
@Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
http.
logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")); 
  } 
}
```

You can also reference a good example on stack overflow using this same method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987207/7548672)

When I had this issue I used this line

```
.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
```

Where

> .logoutSuccessUrl("/login") was the page the user will be redirected to.

You could re-factor your code to something like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {       http
     .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/home", "/account/**", "/price/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/home", "/account/**", "/price/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
     .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/welcome")  
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
        .and()
     .logout()
     .and() // This section is re-factored.
        .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/welcome").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID") //Or try .logoutSuccessUrl("/nradmin/welcome") 
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .permitAll()
        .and()
     .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/welcome")           
        .and()
     .sessionManagement()
        .sessio hinCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
```

---

**Update** : This is a modified version. This is essentially what I use in my project except for this portion:

```
.and()
.exceptionHandling()
.accessDeniedPage("/welcome")
.and()
.sessionManagement()
.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
```

So, I believe it should work; otherwise, I believe it may be a setup issue/configuration that resides somewhere else in your project. Please try the below example.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/nradmin/welcome", "/home", "/account/**", "/price/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/nradmin/welcome")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/nradmin/welcome").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID") 
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/nradmin/welcome")
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
    }
```

Comment: @Jacqueline Cavalcanti - did you try my example? It should work.

Comment: I edited my example above to .logoutSuccessUrl("/welcome") instead of .logoutSuccessUrl("/login"). Could you please retry.

Comment: When you logout the redirect url should be something similar to http://localhost:8080/logout. Then you should see your "/welcome" page. Now, this does not work you can try changing .logoutSuccessUrl("/welcome") to .logoutSuccessUrl("/nradmin/welcome ") as noted in your original post.

Comment: The problem is not that I cannot log out and go to the welcome page. The changing to the welcome page works, after press log out. BUT if I type on the browser url [link](http://localhost:8080/nradmin/home) I still can access the page home even after logging out.

Comment: I see. Q? Is there a need for this ".antMatchers("/home", "/account/**", "/price/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")"    if not can you comment it out. That's the last thing I can see; otherwise, if using my example above does not work it may be something else in your set up.

Comment: @Jacqueline Cavalcanti - I added an update to my original post. Please refer to the update section.

Comment: Is the page /login different from the page /welcome?
If I don't add .defaultSuccessUrl("/home") it never comes to the home page after logging in.
And the problem continues. If I am logged out and type on the url .../home the home page appears...

Comment: Yes, it is different. It provides instructions for Spring security. See here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html#configuring-a-custom-login-page

Comment: I forget to add "/welcome" to this line .antMatchers("/welcome", "/home", "/account/**", "/price/**").hasRole("ADMIN") i updated my last example to include it. Please try the last example again.

Comment: I also edited line .loginPage("/login") to .loginPage("/welcome") which uses your custom URI.

Comment: Added "nradmin" in "/nradmin/welcome" I added it in my last example. If it does not work with it just remove it and try with "/welcome" alone.

Comment: I did what you said, but if I don't add the line: `.defaultSuccessUrl("/home")`
logging in is not possible anymore. I stay on the welcome page.
And if I type on the browser 
[link](http://localhost:8080/nradmin/home) it has access to the home page even though I didn't logging in.

Comment: It is like it is not cleaning a existing session or even creating a session without logging