# Azure Single Sign on does not log out properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, spring-security, single-sign-on

I am working on the jsp-springboot application ,I have implemented the sso using azure and it is working as expected. I have configured

```
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id

azure.activedirectory.client-id

azure.activedirectory.client-secret
```

Also I have added the redirect url as well
In the application.properties , I have not added any configuration classes other that these changes, I am able to login successfully .
For logout I use

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/${​​​​​azure.activedirectory.tenant-id}​​​​​/oauth2/v2.0/logout
```

and when I click logout I get the final page ie
[image]

But if I open a new tab and try to access the application, I will be able to access the application without asking for login. I am not sure what changes I have to make to prevent this

Answer (score 1):

If you require it to single logout, try to set  logout URL. For single sign-out to work correctly, the LogoutURL for the application must be explicitly registered with Azure AD during application registration.

Azure AD supports redirect binding (HTTP GET), and not HTTP POST binding

[image]

But if that’s not working, it may be expected  from v2 endpoint, as  it seems like the known issue with v2 endpoint in azure saml sso .

Try using  v1 logout enDpoint
ex: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout` and change it wherever needed in app .
Please check this reference from
 [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/544011/bypass-the-azure-ad-sso-choose-an-account-prompt-w.html) .

Also see if you need to edit logout url in manifest editor under App Registration .

[image]

**References:**

1. [Azure Single Sign Out SAML Protocol | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-out-saml-protocol#logoutrequest)
2. [java - Implement 'logout' functionality in Spring Boot - Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661492/implement-logout-functionality-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Hi for me,the issue was due to session, I added a filter and invalidated the session for the logout url and I was able to logout successfully

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly have you tried?